# Can I use rss feed of popular websites in my app?

Tags: windows, web-applications, web, rss

I am trying to create windows phone app.
Can I use RSS feed from sites like techcrunch and thenextweb

Comment: Are you asking "Can I" as in, "Is this technically possible" or are you asking "Can I" as in "Am I legally allowed to use their content". You need to add more details about what you're trying to accomplish; it isn't clear right now.

Answer (score 0):

Will you be monetizing your app? If not then you should be able to use the feeds with no problem.

If you plan to monetize your app, then there may be additional terms you need to comply to, but I cannot find any terms relating to the RSS feeds anywhere, so it's likely not to be an issue.

TechCrunch uses Google Feedburner to supply their RSS feed, so you might want to look at [Google's terms of service](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/).